# Strip math related characters from tokenized string

Tags: regex, xslt

I need to parse through string and return whatever is not math-related and return a tokenized string. using xslt v2.0

Input:

`ImfbkMax/sqrt(2)/ImRated*100`

Output:

`ImfbkMax,ImRated`

The following is the xslt. I first split the string by "/" character and then "*" character then get rid of "sqrt(2)" and "100" using regex.

```
<xsl:template match='/'>
<xsl:call-template name='returnVars'><xsl:with-param name='string' select='"ImfbkMax/sqrt(2)/ImRated*100"'/></xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>



    <xsl:template name='returnVars'>
        <xsl:param name='string' select='"."'/>
        <xsl:variable name='vars'><xsl:call-template name='tokenize'><xsl:with-param name='text' select='$string'/><xsl:with-param name='separator' select='"/"'/></xsl:call-template></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name='vars'><xsl:call-template name='tokenize'><xsl:with-param name='text' select='$string'/><xsl:with-param name='separator' select='"*"'/></xsl:call-template></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name='vars'><xsl:value-of select='replace($vars, ",[A-z]+\([0-9]+\)", "")'/></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name='vars'><xsl:value-of select='replace($vars, ",[0-9]+", "")'/></xsl:variable>
    </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
        <xsl:param name="separator" select="','"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(contains($text, $separator))">
                <xsl:element name='item'>
                    <xsl:attribute name='label'><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($text)"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name='value' select='"0"'/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:element name='item'>
                    <xsl:attribute name='label'><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($text, $separator))"/></xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $separator)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Good luck with this, regexp is not really a good general purpose parser.

Comment: Define "math-related". -- BTW, if you're using XSLT 2.0 then why do you need a tokenizing template when XPath 2.0 has a `tokenize()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "math-related" means "containing a digit character", the expected result could be produced simply by:

```
<xsl:value-of select="tokenize(input, '/|\*')[not(matches(., '\d'))]" separator=", "/>
```

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxWZS6T

Answer (score 0):

You can also try a bit more sophisticated regex that you can further customize with the `tokenize` + `replace` approach:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(replace(input, '^(?:sqrt|[^a-zA-Z])+|(?:sqrt|[^a-zA-Z])+$', ''), '(?:sqrt|[^a-zA-Z])+')" separator=", "/>
</xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here,

- `^(?:sqrt|[^a-zA-Z])+|(?:sqrt|[^a-zA-Z])+$` - finds sequences of `sqrt` and any non-letter chars at the start and end of string, and removes them (it is used in `replace`)
- `(?:sqrt|[^a-zA-Z])+` splits with the pattern into chunks.

**NOTE**: You will need to add more "math" words you want to consider/support.